# Removing duplicates from array based on a property in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, unique

I have an array with custom objects. Each array item has a field named "name". Now I want to remove duplicate entries based on this name value.

How should I go about achieving this?

Comment: Are the items in an Objective-C container like NSArray, or C/C++ (e.g., std::vector or a C array)?

Comment: sorry removed the tag, its objective c array with custom objects... "name" is one of its member variable, I want to filter based on this "name" value.

Comment: Check my answer with code example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32136313/988169

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might have to actually write this filtering method yourself:

```
@interface NSArray (CustomFiltering)
@end

@implementation NSArray (CustomFiltering) 

- (NSArray *) filterObjectsByKey:(NSString *) key {
   NSMutableSet *tempValues = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
   NSMutableArray *ret = [NSMutableArray array];
   for(id obj in self) {
       if(! [tempValues containsObject:[obj valueForKey:key]]) {
            [tempValues addObject:[obj valueForKey:key]];
            [ret addObject:obj];
       }
   }
   [tempValues release];
   return ret;
}

@end
```

Comment: its not a string array its a custom object array.... with a string name as the property... I want to filter based in this name property

Comment: @Jacob: Wrote my answer just as you edited yours. You really should use an `NSMutableSet` instead of a `NSMutableArray` for lookups, the performance boost from a hash lookup is quite allot better than a linear search.

Comment: A couple of comments. First, you should just use `[NSMutableSet set]` instead of alloc/init+release. Second, you should use `-member:` instead of `-containsObject:`. `-containsObject:` is documented as returning whether the given object is present in the set, without defining "present". It is reasonable to assume it uses pointer equality. `-member:` is documented as using `-isEqual:`, which is what you actually want to test with.

Comment: Thanks all of you guys... your answers & comments really helped me. Thumbs up for all of you...

Comment: @Kevin, -containsObject: looks for membership the same way as -member: does. The only diff is returning BOOL versus the object itself.

Comment: @Kevin, I used `alloc/init` because I didn't want the set to be sitting around in the autorelease pool. The code only actually *needs* the set to be around while the loop is executing, so this way it can be released from memory at the earliest possible time.

Answer (score 30):

I do not know of any standard way to to do this provided by the frameworks. So you will have to do it in code. Something like this should be doable:

```
NSArray* originalArray = ... // However you fetch it
NSMutableSet* existingNames = [NSMutableSet set];
NSMutableArray* filteredArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (id object in originalArray) {
   if (![existingNames containsObject:[object name]]) {
      [existingNames addObject:[object name]];
      [filteredArray addObject:object];
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks PeyloW your answer was right on spot... thumbs up... I wish you best of luck in your endeavors....

Comment: Shouldn't it be [object objectForKey:@"name"]; in side that loop?

Comment: Really nice solution

Comment: Got SIGABRT on this in 2017 O_O

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question but here is another possibility, depending on what you need.

Apple does provide a way to do this -- [Key-Value Coding Collection Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE).

Object operators let you act on a collection. In this case, you want:

@distinctUnionOfObjects

> The @distinctUnionOfObjects operator returns an array containing the distinct objects in the property specified by the key path to the right of the operator.

`NSArray *distinctArray = [arrayWithDuplicates` `valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.name"];`

In your case, though, you want the whole object. So what you'd have to do is two-fold:
1) Use `@distinctUnionOfArrays` instead. E.g. If you had these custom objects coming from other collections, use `@distinctUnionOfArray.myCollectionOfObjects`
2) Implement `isEqual:` on those objects to return if their .name's are equal

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to get flak for this...

You can convert your array into a dictionary.  Not sure how efficient this is, depends on the implementation and comparison call, but it does use a hash map.

```
//Get unique entries
NSArray *myArray = @[@"Hello", @"World", @"Hello"];
NSDictionary *uniq = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:myArray forKeys:myArray];
NSLog(@"%@", uniq.allKeys);
```

---

## *Note, this may change the order of your array.

Comment: Hehehehe I LOVE this!

Comment: Edit: well I just spent the last 15 minutes fixing a bug in my code. Using this NSDictionary method will NOT keep the ORDER of your array. All my items were scrambled. That's what I get for using hacky wordk-arounds where OP prefaces "I'm going to get flak for this..." lol

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like your custom NSObject subclasses to be considered equal when their names are equal you may implement `isEqual:` and `hash`. This will allow you to add of the objects to an `NSSet`/`NSMutableSet` (a set of distinct objects).

You may then easily create a sorted `NSArray` by using `NSSet`'s `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:`method.

MikeAsh wrote a pretty solid piece about implementing custom equality: [Friday Q&A 2010-06-18: Implementing Equality and Hashing](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-06-18-implementing-equality-and-hashing.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about the order

```
NSArray * newArray =
        [[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:oldArray] array]; **// iOS 5.0 and later**
```

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple in one line

```
NSArray *duplicateList = ...
```

> If you don't care about elements order then (unordered)

```
NSArray *withoutDUP1 = [[NSSet setWithArray:duplicateList] allObjects];
```

> Keep the elements in order then (ordered)

```
NSArray *withoutDUP2 = [[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:duplicateList] array];
```

Comment: But how is your code filtering based on field "name" ?

Answer (score 0):

Implement isEqual to make your objects comparable:

```
@interface SomeObject (Equality)
@end

@implementation SomeObject (Equality)

- (BOOL)isEqual:(SomeObject*)other
{
    return self.hash == other.hash;
}

- (NSUInteger)hash
{
    return self.name;///your case
}

@end
```

How to use:

```
- (NSArray*)distinctObjectsFromArray:(NSArray*)array
{
    return [array valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.self"];
}
```