# Delete duplicate object in flat array

Tags: iphone, ios, arrays

how to delete duplicate object in flat array or json array

My array is like this

`<VideoList2: 0xac46bd0> (entity: VideoList2; id: 0xac64090 <x-coredata://7CD2EB96-C31D-4605-B7AB-13909C6B661B/VideoList2/p982> ; data: {\n    Category = Featured;\n    Duration = nil;\n    image = \"http://files.stora.com/accounts/5053775f0f66021ac50/collection/506c59660023ae100039f/entries/50ae69c00f6602492f001b6f/fields/k509a2cbe0f6602b1/file.jpg\";\n    videoLink = \"http://www.youtube.com/v/yf92pV?rel=0\";\n    videoName = pamala;\n})",`

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Which one is duplicate? Can you please format it properly.

Comment: What you're referring to as a Duplicate Object?

Comment: Possible similar question [stack over flow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978574/removing-duplicates-from-nsmutablearray)

Comment: If you get the answer kindly inform.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove [NSMutableArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object which is identical to other array

This is  deleting of one object which is identical

```
[yourAry removeObject:removingAry];
```

And to remove all identical ary

```
[yourAry removeObject:removingAry];
```

For more detail just read [NSMutableArray Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove duplicates from same array :

```
NSMutableArray *mainArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"A",@"B", nil];

for (NSInteger start=[mainArray count]-1; start>=0; start--) {
    [mainArray removeObjectIdenticalTo:[mainArray objectAtIndex:start] inRange:NSMakeRange(0, start)];
}

NSLog(@"%@",mainArray);
```

Output:

```
(
    C,
    D,
    A,
    B
)
```

If you want to remove same objects contained in different array.

```
NSMutableArray *mainArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D", nil];
NSMutableArray *secArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"B",@"D", nil];

[mainArray removeObjectsInArray:secArray];

NSLog(@"%@",mainArray);
```

Output:

```
(
    A,
    C
)
```