# NSString remove duplicated substrings

Tags: ios, sorting, nsstring, nsscanner

How can I remove duplicated substings from string? For ex. I have: **aaa,bbb,ttt,bbb,rrr**.
And in result I want to have **aaa,bbb,ttt,rrr** (deleted duplicated **bbb**). I hope for your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it in three steps

1) `NSArray *items = [theString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];`

2) remove duplicate element from array

```
    NSArray* array =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"test1", @"test2", @"test1", @"test2",@"test4",   nil];

    NSArray* filteredArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    NSSet *set= [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:array];
    filteredArray = [set allObjects];
```

3) Concate String from array

```
NSString *myString = [myArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

Comment: It would be nice if you added code for step two. Since everyone with a simillar problem probably dont know how to write it.

Comment: You could have googled it, and found it very easily. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978574/removing-duplicates-from-nsmutablearray and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025674/the-best-way-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-nsmutablearray-in-objective-c

Comment: - 1 Please add code for step two into the answer. You shouldn's assume  people know, if that was the case you could assume everyone knows everything. Will add +1 when question is complete.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
NSMutableSet *seen = [NSMutableSet set];
NSMutableString *buf = [NSMutableString string];
for (NSString *s in [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","]) {
    if (![seen containsObject:s]) {
         [seen add:s];
         [buf appendFormat:@",%@", s];
    }
}
NSString *res = [buf length] ? [buf substringFromIndex:1] : @"";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSMutableDictionary;
In dictionary there are two elements;
1. Key
2. Value

Just set Keys as your array elements;
Special point is that 'Key' can't be duplicate;

Now just get array of Keys by using [dictionary allKeys];

Now, at this stage you have unique values in new array;