# Remove duplicates from large NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a large mutable array with lots of duplicate values in alphabetical order.

I need to be able to convert my array *Array into a new array that contains one entry for each string variant.

I am currently using:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:papersObject.paperSubject, nil];

NSCountedSet *paperSet = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:array];
NSMutableArray *namesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[array count]];

[namesSet enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, BOOL *stop){
    if ([paperSet countForObject:obj] == 1) {
        [namesArray addObject:obj];
    }
}];

NSLog(@"%@", namesArray);
```

But this returns a long list of the same array, still with duplicates.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `namesSet`? Is it really a `NSSet` or does it contain duplicates?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing duplicates from NSMutableArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978574/removing-duplicates-from-nsmutablearray)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
NSArray *arrayWithNoDuplicates = [[NSSet setWithArray:papersObject.paperSubject] allObjects];
```

Comment: This will lose the order of the original array.

Comment: Sure, but he didn't say he needed the order maintained. To maintain order, just use an `NSOrderedSet` instead.

Comment: That is, what i wrote. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A. What is namesSet? paperSet?

B. However:

```
NSOrderedSet *set = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:array];
NSArray *arrayWithUniquesIsAnOrderedSet = set.array;
```

BTW: I would highly recommend to use an ordered set instead of an array, because an array with unique objects *is* an ordered set.

Comment: Maybe you meant "an *ordered* array with unique objects is (akin to) an ordered set"?

Comment: No, an array is always ordered via its index. "Ordered" does not mean "sorted". Ordered simply means that you have a concept of "next" and "previous".

Comment: Apologies, my error - as you correctly state an `NSOrderedSet` does go by position and not an ordering on the elements.