# Remove duplicity from array of array iOS SDK

Tags: ios, arrays, nsmutablearray

I have array of array and want to eliminate duplicity. How can I do this

```
<__NSArrayM 0x9175640>(
<__NSArrayI 0x919ec80>(
http://scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfp1/outbound-distilleryimage2/t0.0-17/OBPTH/dccd6b4cb15211e3aeb912af24c9b212_5.jpg,
47738394,
evdokia_bach,
Evdokia Bach,
https://instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net/profiles/profile_47738394_75sq_1388023560.jpg
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x919eca0>(
http://scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xpf1/outbound-distilleryimage10/t0.0-17/OBPTH/e27402bab15011e39584123223ad70da_5.jpg,
47799994,
allen,
allen warden,
https://instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net/profiles/profile_47738394_75sq_1388023560.jpg
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x919ecc0>(
http://scontent-a.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/outbound-distilleryimage6/t0.0-17/OBPTH/5794c4e0b15011e397e2122466b7dba2_5.jpg,
47738394,
evdokia_bach,
Evdokia Bach,
https://instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net/profiles/profile_47738394_75sq_1388023560.jpg
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x919ece0>(
http://scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xpf1/outbound-distilleryimage11/t0.0-17/OBPTH/0f0916eab15011e3942d12c36745260f_5.jpg,
47738394,
evdokia_bach,
Evdokia Bach,
https://instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net/profiles/profile_47738394_75sq_1388023560.jpg
    )
)
)
```

I want only unique array how can i do this ?

Comment: why don't you use `NSSet`

Comment: i have tried but not helpful

Comment: i tried this but not solving my problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/5978744

Comment: If that doesn't work then there aren't exact duplicates in your array.  It looks like your array contains arrays and you want to eliminate duplicates based on one of the elements of the sub array?

Comment: yes man i want to eliminate duplicates based on the elements of the sub array

Comment: Is it the 5th element? e.g. https://instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net/profiles/profile_47738394_75sq_1388023560.jpg ?

Comment: actually first url is different in all subarray , that why asset was not working, so i created new array without first url, after this nsset is working @Paulw11 Thanks