# Objective-C - Removing duplicates with custom sub-objects

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, filtering, nspredicate

I have a pop-down list which lists outbound and inbound airport codes, like this:

```
Leg -- JFK DXB
Leg -- JFK DXB
Leg -- LS14 CFR
Leg -- LS14 EGSG
Leg -- OXF CFR
Leg -- OXF CFR
Leg -- JFK DXB
Leg -- DXB OXF
Leg -- DXB JFK
Leg -- CFR GVA
Leg -- JFK TDX
Leg -- JFK DXB
Leg -- TDX DXB
Leg -- GVA OXF
```

I want to remove all duplicates where the departure and arrival match (ie: JFK - DXB)

The airport codes are custom sub or a third-party object so its not as simple as doing a string comparison.

In the following I am looping through to rid myself of any nil objects

```
    NSArray *charters = [CharterRequest charterRequestsForUser:[User currentUser] inContext:[NSManagedObjectContext mainContext]];

NSMutableArray *charterReq = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (CharterRequest *request in charters)
    {
        CharterRequestLeg *leg = [request initialLeg];
        if ( (leg.departureAirport.code != nil) && (leg.destinationAirport.code != nil) ) {
            [charterReq addObject:request];
        }
    }
```

Eventually I will output the airport codes in terminal

```
// someIndex could be any index, but lets say its 1 for now
    VICCharterRequest *request = charterReq[someIndex];
    VICCharterRequestLeg *leg = [request initialLeg];

    NSString *returnedString =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", leg.departureAirport.code, leg.destinationAirport.code];
    NSLog(@"Leg = %@", returnedString);
```

The problem I have is I get a lot of duplicate destination/arrival airports such as JFK DXB will appear multiple times.

Is there a reasonable way to get rid of all duplicates, leaving uniques?

Many thanks

---

Currently I have this code, it always returns 50.  It should much less than this due to duplicates;

```
// Filter out nils
        for (VICCharterRequest *request in charters)
        {
            VICCharterRequestLeg *leg = [request initialLeg];
            if ( (leg.departureAirport.code != nil) && (leg.destinationAirport.code != nil) ) {
                [list addObject:request];
            }
        }

        NSMutableSet *seenItems = [NSMutableSet set];

        NSPredicate *dupPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock: ^BOOL(id obj, NSDictionary *bind) {

            VICCharterRequestLeg *leg = [obj initialLeg];

            BOOL seen = ([seenItems containsObject:leg.departureAirport] && [seenItems containsObject:leg.destinationAirport]);
            //[seenItems containsObject:leg];

            if (!seen) {
                [seenItems addObject:obj];
            }
            return !seen;
        }];


        NSArray *filtered = [list filteredArrayUsingPredicate:dupPred];
        NSLog(@"Filtered = %lu", filtered.count);
```

Comment: The order does not matter

Comment: Check my answer with code example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32136313/988169

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup some comparable methods.

For example:

```
- (BOOL)isEqualToVICCharterRequest:(VICCharterRequest *)request {
  if (!request) {
    return NO;
  }

  BOOL depEqual = (!self.departureAirport.code && !request.departureAirport.code) || [self.departureAirport.code isEqualToString:request.departureAirport.code];

  BOOL arrEqual = (!self.destinationAirport.code && !request.destinationAirport.code) || [self.birthday isEqualToDate:request.destinationAirport.code];

  return depEqual && arrEqual;
}
```

Then your loop code would be:

```
for (CharterRequest *request in charters)
{
    CharterRequestLeg *leg = [request initialLeg];
    if ( ![request isEqualToVICCharterRequest:leg] ) {
        [charterReq addObject:request];
    }
}
```

And if you want to go deeper:

```
#pragma mark - NSObject

- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object {
  if (self == object) {
    return YES;
  }

  if (![object isKindOfClass:[VICCharterRequest class]]) {
    return NO;
  }

  return [self isEqualToVICCharterRequest:(isEqualToVICCharterRequest *)object];
}

- (NSUInteger)hash {
  return [self.departureAirport.code hash] ^ [self.destinationAirport.code hash];
}
```

Comment: The only issue with this is that `isEqualToVICCharterRequest` has a child VICCharterRequestLeg; but I think I can customise your solution for my requirements

Comment: In the end I just created an array of dictionaries and used the copy I want to display as a unique key, and then did some removal of duplicates based on this key. I found it much easier solution.

Comment: Cool.  There is always more than one way to accomplish a task.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray* array = ... // you can add your data to this array
NSMutableSet* existingset  = [NSMutableSet set];
NSMutableArray* finalArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (id object in array) {
   if (![existingset containsObject:[object name]]) {
      [existingset addObject:[object name]];
      [finalArray addObject:object];
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm currently trying a variation of this; however the issue is that it finalArray always contains exact copy of incoming array.  This is because the check is on  `VICCharterRequestLeg *leg` not on the parent object.  But I will try it anyway, it might solve issue.

Comment: I'm afraid this code would always add the object.  Remember, I'm comparing multiple items, which are `destination airport` and `arrival airport`.    The issue I have is that I need to do the comparison on `VICCharterRequestLeg *leg = [request initialLeg];`