# How do I get unique values from an array

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsarray, nsset

Please note ***this is for OSX, not for iOS.***

I have looked and tried some solutions in other SO questions, but none seem to work for me, hence this:

I want to get a unique set of years out of an array.

My code is this:

```
NSMutableArray * unique = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSMutableSet * processed = [NSMutableSet set];
        for (yearString in yearStringArray) {
            if (![processed containsObject:yearString] == NO) {
                [unique addObject:yearString];
            }
            [processed addObject:yearString];
        }

        NSLog(@"unique: %@",unique );
        NSLog(@"processed: %@",processed );

    }];

The console returns:

unique: (
        (
        1941,
        1942,
        1943,
        1945,
        1948,
        1948,
        1948,
        1949
    )

processed: {(
        (
        1941,
        1942,
        1943,
        1945,
        1948,
        1948,
        1948,
        1949
    )
)}
```

I only want one 1948.  I would appreciate any help.

UPDATES: Thanks for the answers all. Keep em coming please!!!

These are the code snips I've tried now:

1.

```
for (yearString in yearStringArray) {
            if ([processed containsObject:yearString] == NO) {
                [unique addObject:yearString];
            }
            [processed addObject:yearString];
        }
```

2.

```
   NSString *yearString = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSArray *objectArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    [objectArray = objects copy];

    for (int j = 0; j <= objectArray.count; j++) {
        NSString *yearString = [objectArray valueForKey:@"year"];
        [yearStringArray addObject:yearString];
    }


    NSMutableArray * unique = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableSet * processed = [NSMutableSet set];


    for (yearString in yearStringArray) {

        [unique addObject:yearString];
        [processed addObject:yearString];
    }

    NSArray *processed2 = [[NSSet setWithArray:unique] allObjects];
    NSLog(@"unique: %@",unique );
    NSLog(@"processed: %@",processed );
    NSLog(@"processed2: %@",processed2 );
    //[self setYears];
}];
```

3.

```
NSString *yearString = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSArray *objectArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    [objectArray = objects copy];

    for (int j = 0; j <= objectArray.count; j++) {
        yearString = [objectArray valueForKey:@"year"];
        [yearStringArray addObject:yearString];
    }



    NSArray *uniqueYears = [yearStringArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.self"];
    NSLog(@"uniqueYears: %@", uniqueYears);


}];



}
```

Still not getting unique years..

Comment: possible duplicate of [removing duplicates from array in objective c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007427/removing-duplicates-from-array-in-objective-c)

Comment: I tried that answer too Adam. no joy.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

An simple way is to create an `NSSet` from the array with duplicates. The result is a set which by definition stores only the unique objects. Then using NSSet's `-allObjects` method to convert the `NSSet` back to an `NSArray`. The only downside is you lose the original ordering by converting to an `NSSet`.

```
NSArray *uniqueArray = [[NSSet setWithArray:duplicateArray] allObjects];
```

If you need to preserve the ordering and can require 10.7+, you can use an `NSOrderedSet`.

```
NSArray *uniqueArray = [[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:duplicateArray] array];
```

**Edit:**

Thanks to [Mattt Thompson](https://github.com/mattt) in the WWDC 2013 *Session 228 - Hidden Gems in Cocoa and Cocoa Touch*,
there is another way without creating an intermediate set.

```
NSArray *uniqueArray = [duplicateArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.self"]
```

Comment: Andrew, thank you. I used your code (properly this time). The unordered set worked beautifully. Many thanks.

Comment: Also you can mention that  "@distinctUnionOfObjects.self" don't preserve order

Answer (score 8):

You can use the array's `valueForKeyPath` and set it to `distinctUnionOfObjects.self`.

```
NSArray *yearsArray = @[@"1943", @"1945", @"1948", @"1948", @"1948", @"1949"];
NSArray *uniqueYears = [yearsArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.self"];
NSLog(@"uniqueYears: %@", uniqueYears);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Rob, I just realized that I copied this code from one of my projects. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

You provided a `NSLog`:

```
unique: (
    (
    1941,
    1942,
    1943,
    1945,
    1948,
    1948,
    1948,
    1949
    ) 
)
```

This is not an array of strings. This is an array with one object, which is, itself, an array. That suggests that `yearStringArray` has that same structure. Clearly your code (and the name of that variable) suggests you thought it should be otherwise.

You should either fix whatever created `yearStringArray` to actually create an array of strings, or change your code to reflect this structure of `yearStringArray`, e.g.,

```
for (yearString in yearStringArray[0]) 
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, your answer, combined with Andrew's gave me the clue and solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is bug.

```
if (![processed containsObject:yearString] == NO)
```

You have to use

```
if ([processed containsObject:yearString] == NO)
```

or

```
if (![processed containsObject:yearString])
```