# Obj-C: Only return 1 cell (top cell) if cells proceeding contain the same UILabel values?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

The top 3 cells in my tableview have a label that says the word 'Squirrels'. Is there a way to make it so that if a UILabel says 'Squirrels' in more than one cell in my table, to only show the first cell of the three?

> **E.g.** if UILabel userName in tableviewCell is equal to @"Squirrels", only show one table
>   view cell in the table that contains Squirrels in the UILabel

Hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT:** I've successfully retrieved the first array containing more than one common 'name' value (see edit to code below). That said, when I try and display these values (firstFoundObject) in my tableview I get the following crash error:

> -[__NSDictionaryI objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c01a5a20 2017-10-03 23:01:51.728128-0700
>   pawswap[623:85420] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI
>   objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c01a5a20'

**ViewController.m**

```
- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    NSString *nodeTitle = self.messages[0][@"name"];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", nodeTitle];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [self.messages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    id firstFoundObject = nil;
    firstFoundObject =  filteredArray.count > 0 ? filteredArray.firstObject : nil;

    NSMutableArray *firstObjects = firstFoundObject;

   return [firstObjects count];


}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *nodeTitle = self.messages[0][@"name"];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", nodeTitle];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [self.messages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    id firstFoundObject = nil;
    firstFoundObject =  filteredArray.count > 0 ? filteredArray.firstObject : nil;

    NSMutableArray *firstObjects = firstFoundObject;

    static NSString *PointsTableIdentifier = @"MyMessagesCell";

    MyMessagesCell *cell = (MyMessagesCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PointsTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyMessagesCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];


    }




    NSDictionary *receivedSubjectLine = [firstObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *messageSubject = [receivedSubjectLine objectForKey:@"node_title"];


    [cell.subjectLine setText:messageSubject];



    NSDictionary *fromUser = [firstObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *userName = [fromUser objectForKey:@"name"];

    [cell.senderName setText:userName];




    NSDictionary *receivedBody = [firstObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *messageBody = [receivedBody objectForKey:@"body"];

    [cell.fullMessage setText:messageBody];




    NSDictionary *messageReceived = [firstObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *timeReceived = [messageReceived objectForKey:@"published at"];

    NSLog(@"Message Received at %@", timeReceived);

    [cell.receivedStamp setText:timeReceived];




    return cell;

}
```

**PREVIOUS**

**ViewController.m**

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView *)tableview
{
    return 1;
}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return [self.messages count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *PointsTableIdentifier = @"MyMessagesCell";

    MyMessagesCell *cell = (MyMessagesCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PointsTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyMessagesCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSDictionary *receivedSubjectLine = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *messageSubject = [receivedSubjectLine objectForKey:@"node_title"];
    [cell.subjectLine setText:messageSubject];

    NSDictionary *fromUser = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *userName = [fromUser objectForKey:@"name"];
    [cell.senderName setText:userName];

    NSDictionary *receivedBody = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *messageBody = [receivedBody objectForKey:@"body"];
    [cell.fullMessage setText:messageBody];

    NSDictionary *messageReceived = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *timeReceived = [messageReceived objectForKey:@"published at"];
    [cell.receivedStamp setText:timeReceived];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I dont understand your question completely but I think you need to make changes in your datasource which in your case is `self.messages` if you want to change the number of cells in your tableview

Comment: The best solution I think, is to make a secondary array which contains unique elements of `self.messages` and work with this array. To remove duplications from an array see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19373981/3824335.

Comment: I guess you question is not clear much. especially "only show one table view cell in the table that contains Squirrels in the UILabel"?

Comment: See above edit @manismku.

Comment: You can check out my post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the problem you are getting is due to firstObject is of type Dictionary and you are type casting it to NSMutableArray. Please check below line:

> id firstFoundObject = nil; firstFoundObject =  filteredArray.count > 0
>   ? filteredArray.firstObject : nil;

If you see you have filteredArray.firstObject as Dictionary in your application which you capture in firstFoundObject but later you are making it NSMutableArray type here:

> NSMutableArray *firstObjects = firstFoundObject;

And later when you try to get here, it crashes

> NSDictionary *receivedSubjectLine = [firstObjects
>   objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

The correct - basic - version of your code should look like

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 static NSString *PointsTableIdentifier = @"MyMessagesCell";
MyMessagesCell *cell = (MyMessagesCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PointsTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyMessagesCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

[cell.subjectLine setText:[self.recvMessage objectForKey:@"node_title"]];
[cell.senderName setText:[self.recvMessage objectForKey:@"name"]];
[cell.fullMessage setText:[self.recvMessage objectForKey:@"body"]];
[cell.receivedStamp setText:[self.recvMessage objectForKey:@"published at"]];

return cell;        
}
```

Though it is not optimised but still it can do work for you.

**COUNT ISSUE:**

> NSMutableDictionary *firstObjects = firstFoundObject;
>       return [firstObjects count];

In your code above you have inside the *numberOfRowsInSection* since you have firstFoundObject as dictionary so when you call [firstObjects count] which is a valid call and it returns the number of key in the dictionary.

You have modify it like :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{

     NSInteger rowCount = filteredArray.count;
self.recvMessage = rowCount? filteredArray.firstObject: nil;
return rowCount? 1: 0;

}
```

and you have new data which actually stores the filtered object.

```
@property (nonatomic) NSDictionary  *recvMessage;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't crash (hooray!) and it filters (YAY), however, for some reason it's showing the same first item like 11 times? Ha ha ha.

Comment: I made the edit you made above, and it still returns 11 of the same. Though my filteredArray contains 11 *different* results for name == nodeTitle, so I assume that's why. The above is showing the FIRST result in my tableview 11 times... I simply want it to show the first result of my filtered items ONCE lol

Comment: That's weird. But have modified all the methods. It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it easily, 
You will do it before run tableView, 
for example :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{

[super viewDidLoad];


    NSMutableDictionary* NameDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    NSString* PreviousName;

    int oneTime=0;

    for(int i=0;i<[self.messages count];i++){

        NSDictionary *fromUser = [self.messages objectAtIndex: i];

        NSString *userName = [fromUser objectForKey:@"name"];

        if(oneTime==0)
        {

            PreviousName=userName;

            [NameDictionary addObject:[self.messages objectAtIndex: i]];

            oneTime=1;
        }

        if(oneTime!=0)
        {

            if([PreviousName isEqualToString: userName])
            {

            }

            else{

                [NameDictionary addObject:[self.messages objectAtIndex: i]];

            }

            PreviousName=userName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: self.messages is an NSMutableArray (so I've changed NSMutableDictionary to that, and then the above code doesn't throw an error). That said, I place the above inside viewDidLoad, and nothing seems to happen? I even log the if statements, and they don't even appear to be triggered? However if I paste the above code in NumberOfRowsInSection, the code is triggered, but no filtering occurs?

Comment: Kindly Send me your project on my mail, mail in on my profile. i will try to fix it according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

When you ask to filter out cells with a senderName property equal to @"Squirrels", you're effectively asking to change your datasource after it has been set. This will cause problems in your numberOfRowsInSection method, which will return more rows than you need if any filtering takes place after the datasource is set.

As one of the comments to your answer suggests, "make a secondary array which contains unique elements of self.messages and work with this array." The array that makes up the datasource of the tableview should require no filtering. The tableview should just be able to present it.

If I had enough reputation to comment on the above answer, I would say that you're right that it doesn't work because self.messages doesn't change. Instead of collecting the "non-duplicate" objects in NameDictionary, consider collecting them in an NSMutableArray. This new, filtered array should be the datasource for your array. You may want to filter this array outside of this ViewController so that once the array arrives at this view controller it can just be assigned to self.messages.

If you're looking to exclude all duplicates, as opposed to just duplicates that appear next to each other, consider this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007427/removing-duplicates-from-array-in-objective-c).