# If item in loops exists more than once remove issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops

```
[myItem enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if (obj isEqualToString:@"someString" > 1) { // not correct syntax
        self.someLabel.text = [self.someLabel.text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\t\t%@\n", obj]];
    }
}];
```

I am trying to check if obj is equal to "someString". And if "someString" is displayed more than one I would like to remove it from the obj.

"itemOne"

"otherItem"

"someString"

"someString" <- remove

"someString" <- remove

I am having issues dynamically doing this within the loop in objective c.

Comment: Is the order of the elements important to you?

Comment: Basically a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1025674/558933 . Check out some of the answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [removing duplicates from array in objective c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007427/removing-duplicates-from-array-in-objective-c)

Comment: Order does not matter, I used @Vidhyanand900 solution below and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution is to convert the array to an ordered set and then back to an array. This will remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
UniqArray = [CurrentArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.self"];
```

or

```
NSArray *UniqArray = [[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:CurrentArray]allObjects];
```

or

```
NSArray *UniqArray = [[NSSet setWithArray:CurrentArray] allObjects]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to an ordered set, which removes the duplicates, then convert it back to an array.

```
// remove duplicates
NSOrderedSet *myItemSet = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:myItem];

// convert it back to NSArray
NSArray *myItemArrayWithoutDuplicates = myItemSet.array;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use continue statement for displaying the data without dublicates

```
[myItem enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj isEqualToString:@"someString"]) { 
        self.someLabel.text = [self.someLabel.text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\t\t%@\n", obj]];
     continue;
    }
}];
```

This will exist from current iteration after value assigned in label.

If you want to delete the dublicate objects. If Order of Items does not matter...

```
NSArray *itemsArray = [[NSSet setWithArray: myItem] allObjects];
```

If order of items matter..

```
 NSMutableArray *uniqueItems = [NSMutableArray array];
for (id item in myItem)
    if (![uniqueItems containsObject:item])
        [uniqueItems addObject:item];
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: That worked well. Thank you! Order did not matter so I used the first one.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

```
let array = ["itemOne", "otherItem", "someString", "someString", "someString"]

print(array) // "itemOne", "otherItem", "someString", "someString", "someString"]

var set = Set<String>()
for item in array{
    set.insert(item)
}

print(set) // ["otherItem", "someString", "itemOne"]
```