# Remove repetitive keys value from NSArray

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray

```
{
        ImageName = "http://192.168.1.8:9701/190214/190214_image2_08_13_2016_11_55_44.jpg";
        ImagePath = "<null>";
        ImageTypeId = 2;
    },
        {
        ImageName = "http://192.168.1.8:9701/190214/190214_image3_08_13_2016_11_55_45.jpg";
        ImagePath = "<null>";
        ImageTypeId = 3;
    },
        {
        ImageName = "http://192.168.1.8:9701/190214/190214_image4_08_13_2016_11_55_48.jpg";
        ImagePath = "<null>";
        ImageTypeId = 4;
    },
        {
        ImageName = "http://192.168.1.8:9701/190214/190214_image5_08_13_2016_11_55_51.jpg";
        ImagePath = "<null>";
        ImageTypeId = 5;
    },
        {
        ImageName = "http://192.168.1.8:9701/190214/190214_image6_08_13_2016_11_55_53.jpg";
        ImagePath = "<null>";
        ImageTypeId = 6;
    },
        {
        ImageName = "http://192.168.1.8:9701/190214/190214_image0_08_13_2016_06_15_21.jpg";
        ImagePath = "<null>";
        ImageTypeId = 0;
    },
        {
        ImageName = "http://192.168.1.8:9701/190214/190214_image1_08_13_2016_07_19_57.jpg";
        ImagePath = "<null>";
        ImageTypeId = 1;
    },
        {
        ImageName = "http://192.168.1.8:9701/190214/190214_image1_08_13_2016_07_19_57.jpg";
        ImagePath = "<null>";
        ImageTypeId = 1;
    }
)
```

I want to remove all the objects whose key is repetitive
For Ex. ImageTypeId = 1; object is two time so want to remove 1 object and only one object with ImageTypeId = 1;

Comment: i need unique ImageTypeId = 1 values

Comment: Do you need to preserve the order?

Comment: No , Just dont need duplicate ImageTypeId , it should be unique

Comment: You could put them into a dictionary using the ID as the key. You could also use `reduce` to build a new array and check each element.

Comment: May i have code hint , as i tried that but fails

Comment: What type of object do you have inside the `NSArray`? Can I see how it is populated?

Comment: that is what in above question

Comment: Something like here but i need in swift http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007427/removing-duplicates-from-array-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary to hold the values:

```
var dict = [NSObject: AnyObject]()
```

Add each item to the dictionary using the `typeid` as the key:

```
for item in arr {
    guard let typeid = item["ImageTypeId"] as? NSObject else { continue }
    dict[typeid] = item
}
```

Create an array with the dictionary values:

```
let newarray = Array(dict.values)
```